# Reference libraries from AspNetCore framework in PowerShell binary module

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core

I'm writing a PowerShell (v7) binary module for managing AspNetCore Data Protection keys, so my module references `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll` from Microsoft ASP.NET Core framework.
I'm getting the following error when importing the module:

```
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The only way to resolve this issue is to publish my module as self-contained library, so that all dependencies are published alongside the module library.

Are there any other options to reference AspNetCore framework from a PowerShell binary module?